# Android adding a cp866 Charset

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement cp 866 support to my Android application. I use InteliJ Idea Community Edition 12.0.3. I want to put `META-INF\service\java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider` file into my `.apk`. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

All files in META-INF-folders are ignored by [JavaResourceFilter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/10e712627b86b2b0061dbd3a20f5f966b2cd7330/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/internal/build/JavaResourceFilter.java) which is used by [ApkBuilder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/e54608a9498ced0348c84cf87f90dfebe907429a/android/common/src/org/jetbrains/android/compiler/tools/AndroidApkBuilder.java).

The only way to include these files into your apk is to put them there after packaging.

I just did a little customization to build.xml in android-sdk and it works well.

See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898409/keep-meta-inf-services-files-in-apk).