# Any freeware java library to encode from Unicode to CP866?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, cyrillic, cp866

I'm trying to print to a device which supports CP866 encoding only.

Unfortunately the device from which I'm printing (an Android device) does not support CP866, resulting in `"abc".getBytes("CP866")` throwing the `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

So, I guess, I have to do `Unicode` to `CP866` encoding myself. Is there any freeware java library that does that?

Comment: According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) CP866 is supported out-of-the-box on every install of the Oracle Java 7 Runtime. What JRE/JDK do you use? Which version?

Comment: Sidenote: "freeware" is an ... ancient term with a very specific meaning. Hardly any software these days is released as freeware. You're *probably* looking for either "open source" or "free software" (or simply "freely available" software).

Comment: 1.6 because my sending device is an Android phone

Comment: so the code runs on Android? Then chances are they've got an *entirely different* (and probably much smaller) set of supported encodings. Why not just [transmit data as UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/)? Everyone supports *that*.

Comment: Nah, the receiving device supports only Cp866. It's a Russian device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305166 has the list of characters; should no pre-made option work, writing code to iterate through an array translating Unicode characters to bytes suitable for CP866 shouldn't take much time at all.

Comment: Turned out, I've spent less time on that than on searching for any library. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

According to the Oracle documentation, Cp866 is a supported encoding for Java 7.  So either

- you are using an old version of Java that doesn't support Cp866 (e.g. see @Joachim's comment!!!), or
- the Java runtime is not recognizing the name you are using.  (The canonical name for the charset is `"Cp866"` not `"CP866"`.)

**UPDATE** - it is unlikely to be the latter.  From what I can make out from [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/cs/FastCharsetProvider.java), the charset lookup mechanism used by the standard "provider" is case insensitive.

References:

- [Supported Encodings in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Supported Encodings in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)
- [Supported Encodings in Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Comment: In Java 5 that encoding was [provided by `charsets.jar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html), which isn't always installed (depending on the language settings of the computer). [Java 6 already had it in `rt.jar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Comment: In Java 6 this is supported (according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)).

Comment: My sending device is an Android device. It has Java 1.6. "abc".getBytes("Cp866") throws an exception. So do I use any other code instead?

Comment: @Alex: Android is **not** Java 1.6. It's "something similar to Java" (google for Dalvik). I assume they only support a small set of encodings (because there's less of a legacy story on Android).

Comment: Hm ... [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074225/android-adding-a-cp866-charset) is related, but doesn't have a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

The class `java.nio.charset.Charset` supports both Cp866 and of course Unicode. I guess you could use that with the `encode` and `decode` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was needed to encode string with Cp866 in android. You can use java library with made up charset classes. Cp866 among them.

This is the link: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~awl03/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/miro/browser/trunk/gcc/libjava/classpath/gnu/java/nio/charset

If you want extend Charset class and add you private Charset: 
[Java NIO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002882). Chapter 6 Character sets