# Browser/parser for icudt48l.dat on Android?

Tags: android, character-encoding, icu

New releases of one mail program fail to run on my Android phone.
Program authors ignored bug report for half year then closed it like 
invalid because "there maybe (sic!) some (sic!) method is missing in Charset class on your phone, ask your vendor to fix it." On different unrelated devices, yes...

What about method, as far as i understand, if the applciation would require a 
missing class/method, then Java (and even Dalvik?) just would not allow this 
application to start (unless hacked ClassLoader used). So the question is to 
find some program that can enumerate what methods are present, which locales 
are present and such. And, probability exists, that all methods are in-place 
but just not all parameters (like charsets) are recognised.

Exploring what can i do here i managed to find /system/usr/icu/icudt48l.dat 
sized 7.8 MB

How can i check if

1. this file is in ICU4j or ICU4c format ?
2. which tables does it contain ?
3. whether it matches the installed ICU version or what ICU binaries version 
   is?
4. Judging by [Android adding a cp866 Charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074225) - Android is only bound to have SOME charset tables. Which charsets are mandatory, and which are optional by Android 4 specs ?

I have Android 4.1 phone and i can copy files to Windows box for examination.

PS. Maybe also someone knows if there is some relatively lightweight tool for 
checking CharSet methods presence and compliance. I cannot use Android CDT 
here for its huge size and requirement to run on Linux, nori am sure that CDT 
has tests for all the world languages

PPS. Perhaps despite parsing binary file this is a more user's questions than programmer's one. I looked at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android but.. seems the Android power-users community there is next to non-existsing.

Answer (score 1):

ICU comes with a tool called [icupkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/icupkg.8.html) that allows you to extract/list/etc. the contents of a .dat

Comment: I see i can get ICU4C binaries at http://site.icu-project.org/download/48 which who knows if can extract and build icu4j data file... 
But the file probably comes form ICU4J seems not to contain those utils ( http://apps.icu-project.org/icu-jsp/downloadPage.jsp?ver=4.8.1.1&base=j ). But thanks anyway

Comment: You can manipulate the .dat files using the tools from the ICU4C binaries just fine. Anyway, the .dat that comes on Android devices is mostly accessed via C (e.g. at the 'system' level)